# Magento 2.2.2 Upgrade failed due to Dotmailer severe issues API endpoint

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I hope someone else has seen this issue. We do have an email program to send follow-on emails to clients after a set time in our previous 2.1.9 install.

We upgraded using composer to 2.2.1 and all "looked good" (not thoroughly tested).

So we decided since 2.2.2 is better than 2.2.1 - to try that upgrade. On web set up wizard it just stops on update pending. On trying the upgrade with composer it seems to go smoothly but when admin or web site is opened there is a big error and the exception log shows

main.CRITICAL: Dotmailer connector API endpoint cannot be empty. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(code: 0): Dotmailer connector API endpoint cannot be empty.

I don't know how dot mailer could think that I had ever used it. But regardless, is there a way to upgrade and INSIST that dotmailer not be added? Or is there a fix for this issue? Workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I've created a github issue to look at this:

https://github.com/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/issues/495

We've identified a cron job that is attempting to initialise the api without checking if its enabled first. We're looking for other places that similar behaviour may be happening.